# ResolveUrl not working with localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem with images in my website. When using relative paths for the image source, it works in development but not in deployment. So I implemented the code below:

```
<script>
   var baseUrl = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>";

   var src = baseUrl + "/images/somegif.gif";

   $(".loading").attr("src", src);

</script>
```

The problem is when checking the value of baseUrl, it is "/". How do I get it to be a value of : "http://localhost:[portnumber]/" ?

Unfortunately, because of logistics, I have not yet been able to test this on deployed website yet. But I need it to work for both development and deployment.

- I am using Visual Studio 2015, running local on IIS Express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to care about the host and the port and you can use just:

```
var src = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/somegif.gif") %>' ;
$(".loading").attr("src", src);
```

It should work in dev and prod environments. If you really need the full path you can use `Request.Url.Scheme`, `Request.Url.Host` and `Request.Url.Port` to construct an absolute url.

Basically, to specify path for Html elements in Asp.Net you have three options:

**1)** Using an **absolute path in Html format** e.g. `/images/somegif.gif`. You can use it in any part of your application and it it will work. It will be the same as

```
http://localhost:[port]/images/somegif.gif
```

and

```
http://your-production.domain/images/somegif.gif
```

for dev and prod respectively in case when `images` folder is in root folder of website. But this may be inconvinient when you move your page and image from one folder to another. hen you can use the second option. Also it may fail when you make your website as a child apllication in IIS. Then you can use the third option.

**2)** Using a **relative path in Html format** e.g. `images/somegif.gif`. If your page is in `/someFolder/page.aspx` the path `images/somegif.gif` will be the same as:

```
http://localhost:[port]/someFolder/images/somegif.gif
```

and

```
http://your-production.domain/someFolder/images/somegif.gif
```

for dev and prod respectively

**3)** Using **~ operator** in Asp.Net. You can use it with server controls or with functions like `ResolveUrl()`. This approach is more preferred than first because it doesn't have the described above flaws.